# Arduino problems

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, assignment-operator, arduino-esp8266

I have a problem. I'm working with Arduino but i'm not good with C++ and i take a error. I work on active security system. I used to motion sensor, RFID, embedded clock and wifi modele. But i say, i take a error Can you help me ?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

String agAdi = "";
String agSifresi = "";

int rxPin = 3;
int txPin = 5;
int RST_PIN = 9;
int SS_PIN = 10;
int CLK_PIN = 6;
int DAT_PIN = 7;
int PST_PIN = 4;
int buzzerPin = 2;
int pirPin = 8;
int hareket;
int tarih;
int saat;

String ip = "";
MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
byte ID[4] = {47, 219, 106, 81};
byte okunandeger[4];

virtuabotixRTC myRTC(CLK_PIN, DAT_PIN, RST_PIN);

SoftwareSerial esp(rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);

  myRTC.setDS1302Time(00, 57, 22, 7, 23, 1, 2022);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  rfid.PCD_Init();

  Serial.println("Started");
  esp.begin(115200);
  esp.println("AT");
  Serial.println("AT Yollandı");
  while (!esp.find("OK")) {
    esp.println("AT");
    Serial.println("ESP8266 Bulunamadı.");
  }
  Serial.println("OK Komutu Alındı");
  esp.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
  while (!esp.find("OK")) {
    esp.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
    Serial.println("Ayar Yapılıyor....");
  }
  Serial.println("Client olarak ayarlandı");
  Serial.println("Aga Baglaniliyor...");
  esp.println("AT+CWJAP=\"" + agAdi + "\",\"" + agSifresi + "\"");
  while (!esp.find("OK"))
    ;
  Serial.println("Aga Baglandi.");
  delay(1000);
}
void loop() {
  saatModulu();
  rfidGiris();

  byte okunankart[4] = rfid.uid.uidByte[];
  int saat = String(myRTC.hours + ":" + myRTC.minutes + ":" + myRTC.seconds);
  int tarih = String(myRTC.dayofmonth + ":" + myRTC.month + ":" + myRTC.year);

  espFonk();
  rfidCikis();

  okunankart = rfid.uid.uidByte[];
  int saat = String(myRTC.hours + ":" + myRTC.minutes + ":" + myRTC.seconds);
  int tarih = String(myRTC.dayofmonth + ":" + myRTC.month + ":" + myRTC.year);

  espFonk();
}

void espFonk() {
  esp.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + ip + "\",80");
  if (esp.find("Error")) {
    Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART Error");
  }
  String veri = "GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=";
  veri += "&field1=";
  veri += String(okunankart);
  veri += "&field2=";
  veri += String(saat);
  veri += "&field3=";
  veri += String(tarih);
  veri += "\r\n\r\n";
  esp.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
  esp.println(veri.length() + 2);
  delay(2000);
  if (esp.find(">")) {
    esp.print(veri);
    Serial.println(veri);
    Serial.println("Veri gonderildi.");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("Baglantı Kapatildi.");
  esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  delay(1000);
}

void rfidGiris() {
  if (!rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) return;
  if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) return;

  if (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == ID[0] && rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == ID[1] &&
      rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == ID[2] && rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == ID[3]) {
    Serial.println("Güvenlik Sistemi Aktif!");
    ekranaYazdir();
    hareketSensor();
  }

  else {
    Serial.print("Yetkisiz Kart");
    ekranaYazdir();
    melodi(500);
    delay(500);
    melodi(500);
  }

  rfid.PICC_HaltA();
}

void ekranaYazdir() {
  Serial.print("ID Numarası : ");
  for (int sayac = 0; sayac < 4; sayac++) {
    Serial.print(rfid.uid.uidByte[sayac]);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
}

void saatModulu() {
  myRTC.updateTime();

  Serial.print("Tarih / Saat: ");
  Serial.print(myRTC.dayofmonth);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(myRTC.month);
  Serial.print("/");
  Serial.print(myRTC.year);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(myRTC.hours);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(myRTC.minutes);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(myRTC.seconds);

  delay(1000);
}

void hareketSensor() {
  hareket = digitalRead(pirPin);

  if (Hareket == HIGH) {
    melodi(5000);
  }
}

int melodi(int dly) {
  tone(buzzerPin, 832);
  delay(dly);
  noTone(buzzerPin);
  delay(dly);
}

void rfidCikis() {
  if (!rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) return;
  if (!rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) return;

  if (rfid.uid.uidByte[0] == ID[0] && rfid.uid.uidByte[1] == ID[1] &&
      rfid.uid.uidByte[2] == ID[2] && rfid.uid.uidByte[3] == ID[3]) {
    Serial.println("Güvenlik Sistemi Deaktif!");
    ekranaYazdir();
    hareket = LOW;
  }

  else {
    Serial.print("Yetkisiz Kart");
    ekranaYazdir();
    melodi(500);
    delay(500);
    melodi(500);
  }

  rfid.PICC_HaltA();
}
```

This is error:
**main.ino:166:8: note: suggested alternative: 'hareket'
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before ']' token**

And Arduino IDE lighting

```
okunankart = rfid.uid.uidByte[];
```

Comment: The error message tells you there's an error in line 166. It even suggests an alternative. You wrote "Hareket" with a big "H", while you declared the variable with a small "h". C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: Don't change the question after someone already posted an answer.

Comment: You are posting the code for an active security system on a public forum? Are you that sure its vulnerabilities are that well managed?

Answer (score 2):

For starters arrays do not have the assignment operator

```
okunankart = rfid.uid.uidByte[];
```

and in any case the expression with empty brackets is wrong.

The initializer in this declaration

```
byte okunankart[4] = rfid.uid.uidByte[];
```

is also wrong.

You need to copy elements from one array in another array for example using the standard algorithm `std::copy` or the C function `memcpy`.

Comment: I'm update the code. Please check this. But this time lighting 
```
String tarih = String(String(myRTC.dayofmonth) + ":" + String(myRTC.month) + ":" + String(myRTC.year);
 ```

Comment: @koray.gnsl You should do that. Otherwise the question and answers only confuse readers.  You should close this question and ask a new question that describes a new problem.  In the pointed line remove leading String(